# Apply different formula based on selection in a dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

How can I achieve such a result?

[image: Addition]

[image: Multiplication]

Of course, this is a simplified example, the formulas I want to use are much more complex, so I'd like to avoid having something like `=ifs($E$3="Addition", A2+B2, $E$3="Multiplication", A2*B2)` in the `result` cells, but have the formula inside the `result` cells really change depending on what's chosen in the dropdown menu :

- if `Addition` is selected, C2 should be `=A2+C2`
- if `Multiplication` is selected, C2 should be `=A2*C2`

Comment: "I'd like to avoid having something like =ifs($E$3="Addition", A2+B2, $E$3="Multiplication", A2*B2)" any reasoon for that?

Comment: Because the formulas in four tables will depend on what will be chosen in the dropdown menu, and I don't want to deal with `ifs` in 200+ cells

Comment: you mean 200+ cells in a column?

Comment: No, in each of my four tables, which are interdependent. I know how to do it with `ifs`, and it's a nightmare, hence my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. Ideally, for each of the four tables, I'd like to have one outside cell (say A1) use `=ìfs(dropdown="algo1", B1, dropdown="algo2", B2, dropdown="algo3", B3, dropdown="algo4", B4)`, have the different formulas in B1, B2, B3, B4, and then have all the cells in the table use the formula in A1.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(E1="addition",       QUERY(A1:B, "select A+B label A+B''"),
 IF(E1="multiplication", QUERY(A1:B, "select A*B label A*B''"), ))
```

[image: 0]

### _______________________________________________________________

```
=IF(E60="addition",       {F60:F},
 IF(E60="multiplication", {G60:G}, 
 IF(E60="division",       {H60:H}, 
 IF(E60="subtraction",    {I60:I}, ))))
```

[image]

Comment: @FrançoisM. if you don't want to bulk all your algorithms in `IFS` than you can set up aux columns and then just call for ranges